# psycopg2 query returns None

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am new to python and programming in general.  This bit of code will eventually be used in a larger application. I apologize ahead of time for any mistakes.  I am trying to make a simple query from a table in a postgresql database.  The only result comes back as None.  Even though I know there is data there.  Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
import psycopg2

def connect():
    """Connects to the database so you can query the stats you require"""

    conn= psycopg2.connect("dbname='Nascar_Stats' user='postgres' \
                       host='localhost' password='xxxxxxxx'")
    print('Connected to DB')

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT 'Track_Length' FROM t_tracks \
                     WHERE 'Track_ID' = 'Daytona';")

    length = cur.fetchone()
    print('Track Length = ', length)

    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the quotes around the `Track_Length` and `Track_ID`. Because of the quotes, column names are currently interpreted as actual strings leading to an unsatisfied comparison between strings `Track_ID` and `Daytona`. Which leads to 0 rows matching the query and `length` getting the `None` value.

Remove the single quotes around the column names:

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT Track_Length 
    FROM t_tracks
    WHERE Track_ID = 'Daytona'
""")
```

Comment: Or use double quotes around table names.